# RPMBUILD - Creating logic on %files section in .spec file

Tags: linux, bash, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I'm pretty new to the rpmbuild stuff, and I wanted to ask if there is a possibility to create following logic in the .spec file:

- in the .spec I have a list of files under %files section let's say:

```
%files
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
/tmp/FileA
/tmp/FileB
/tmp/FileC
```

- So now I want to create the logic like: if FileA exists on the host, don't replace FileB create FileB.new

Is that possible in rpmbuild?

Thank you in advance

Comment: don't you mean "if *fileB* exists on host"?

Answer (score 0):

If your question is really:

> if **fileA** exists on hosts, don't replace **fileB** it but create **fileB.new**

Then this is possible; **yes** but I would **not** recommend this. One of the strong points of (`rpm`) packages is that they know exactly what files they own. If you know that a package is installed you should exactly know the final state. In this case your final state will depend on what was present when installing your package.

This being said, this is quite **dirty**, but you could do something like this:

```
%post
if ! [ -e /tmp/fileA ]
then
    cp /tmp/FileB.template /tmp/fileB
fi

%files
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
/tmp/FileB.template
%ghost /tmp/fileB
```

**NOTES:** `/tmp/fileB` is not immediately installed by your package, but the `%ghost` directive makes sure that (when it appears) it belongs to your package anyways. It will thus be removed when removing your package. Also other packages won't be able to own the same file.

---

If your question is

> if **fileB** exists on hosts, don't replace it but create **fileB.new**

then you can use the `%config(noreplace)` directive:

```
%files
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
/tmp/FileA
%config(noreplae) /tmp/FileB
/tmp/FileC
```

for more information on the behavior of the `%config` directives, this is a very good page: https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~jw35/docs/rpm_config.html

Comment: Hi, thx for the answer. I already use for my specific files the %config(noreplace) macro and that works well for a defined file. But I am really looking for an option to say like: If FileA exists == FileB.new not the same file :) do you maybe know how to achieve that? Thx in advance

Comment: I am trying to write an answer, but something is not clear: `fileA` also belongs to your package? so you just want to do something special if a previous version of your package was already installed?

Comment: yes it is right. Your package cannot just provide `tmp/fileB`because then you would crush it each time. Since you want a strange condition, this is a workaround where your package provides a template which is put in place under some condition.

Comment: I am getting an error that the FileB.template is not found, so something with the section %files is not okay, right? do I need to "ghost" that file too?

Comment: logical. you should rename your `fileB` to `fileB.template` in the `%install` section. I changed its name on purpose such that finally on the system you can call it what you like...

Answer (score 0):

Use a file manifest (%files -f manifest), and construct the contents of the manifest at the end of %install.

With sub-packages, construct multiple manifests at the end of the %install build section.